# How to achieve lazyVertical grid like in LazyColumn in JetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

How to achieve like this layout in Lazycolumn. this is can be done with lazy vertical Grid but how to do it with Lazy column like first layout column with two grid cells in one row and so on with a list of data ex (categories ) and the next layout with 3grids rows (data products). in jetPack compose [image: example image]

Comment: You can use ```LazyVerticalGrid``` and whenever required use ```GridCellCount``` to make changes in layout. I have done like this task before using ```GridCellCount```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridItemSpan` on `item{}` scope fun

```
 val cellCount = 2


LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = modifier,
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(cellCount),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 30.dp, top = 10.dp, start = 5.dp),
) {
item(span = { GridItemSpan(cellCount) }) {
 // one item on a row
 }
item() { // Two items }

}
```

Note: `GridItemSpan` is stable now on the latest compose version