# FlowRow moves items in new row when there's calculation made to fit both items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I need to mimic the way LazyVerticalGrid works but i need it nested in a LazyColumn. I need to have 2 items in a row.
Since the way to do it is to use FlowRow instead, I have the following.

```
  val itemWidth =
        remember { (screenConfiguration.screenWidthDp.dp - 48.dp) / 2}
    FlowRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            ) {
                itemsList.forEach {
                    ItemContainer(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .requiredWidth(itemWidth)
                            .requiredHeight(120.dp),
                        titleRes = it.titleRes,
                        iconRes = it.iconRes,
                    )
                }
            }
```

The 48.dp in the itemWidth is because i have padding of 16.dp on both sides, and 16.dp between the items.
It worked so far but i noticed that on some devices, the items are being arranged one under another.

It also happens if the Screen zoom of device is increased/decreased (not always the same values trigger the bug).

Has anyone encountered this or has a fix for this issue?
Is there a way i can force each row to have 2 items, spaced by 16.dp with each row having padding of 16.dp on start and end, with the items taking up the available space?

Comment: You don't need FlowRow for that task. Setting Modifier.heightIn(max) with some finite value bigger than total contant height, 1000.dp or 2000.dp,  will let you have a LazyVerticalGrid inside LazyColumn. What's not allowed is having a LazyList with Constraints.Infinity which comes with parent that is scrollable in same direction. If you change it to a some finite number your LazyVerticalGrid gets measured with a range between 0 and 1000.dp for instance and gets height of total height of Content. This number sets the biggest height it can get

Comment: You can use `LazyVerticalGrid` and cell the items' column, like `item(span = { GridItemSpan(cellCount) }) { // LazyColumn }`

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77374969/13436099